# How to limit ftw depth without nftw

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to find a way to limit the depth of a file tree walk (ftw) without using nftw. Is there a simple way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No simple way. Use proper tools to do the job.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for your answer. However I'm a bit concerned about nftw because from what I understand it requires a line similar to this `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE = 500` which doesn't work on all operative systems. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Which systems are you targeting?